# tire puzzle with probability

Tags: probability

Four students decide they need an extra day to cram for a Monday
exam. They leave town for the weekend, returning Tuesday.
Producing dated receipts for hotel and other expenses, they explain
that their car suffered a flat tire, and that they did not have a spare.
The professor agrees to give them a make-up exam in the form of
a single written question. The students take their seats in separate
corners of the exam room, silently crowing over their deceptive
triumph—until the professor writes the question on the blackboard:
“Which tire?”
Assuming that the students had not agreed in advance on the
identification of the tire in their story, what is the probability that all
four students will identify the same tire?

Will it be 1/64 or something else.

Comment: If we were to assume that each student picks a tire uniformly and independently at random, the probability that the second person's choice matches the first person is $\frac{1}{4}$, that the third person also matches is $\frac{1}{4}$ and that the fourth person also matches is $\frac{1}{4}$.  The product of these is indeed $\frac{1}{64}$.

Comment: Assuming each chooses a tire with equal probability, the answer is $1/64$.

Comment: @MarceloFornet the answer of $\frac{1}{256}$ answers the probability that they all pick the front left tire., it does not answer the question of finding the probability that they all pick the *same* tire (*which might or might not have been the front-left tire*)

Comment: Well if they start tapping with their left or right hand or foot, it could be significantly much better than 1/64.

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1: there are $4^4$ possible outcomes (ways they could answer the question), and there are only $4$ ways for them to agree on the same tire (one way for each tire). So the probability is $\frac{4}{4^4}$.

Approach 2: No matter how the first person answers, there is a $1/4$ chance that the second person matches the first person's answer. Similarly, the third and fourth people each have a $1/4$ chance of matching the first person's answer. So the probability is $\frac{1}{4^3}$.

Answer (score 0):

As there is 4 tires, lets first guess it is the first tire:

$1/4$ for the first student to choose it,

$1/4$ for the second student to choose it,

$1/4$ for the third student to choose it,

...

In total, multiplied, it is $(1/4)^4$, $1/4$ for the chance they choose the first option, with the exponent $4$, for $4$ people.

Because that could happen for *each* of the 4 tires, we multiply 4 again.

$$4 * (1/4)^4 = (1/4)^3 = 1/(4*4*4) = 1/64$$

This proves you were right with your answer of $1/64$.